# Zoom capability gone

Tags: keyboard, macos

I used to be able to hit Ctrl and use mouse wheel to zoom in on pictures, web pages, or whatever.  With OS 10.8 the mouse wheel just scrolls up and down pages. Any thoughts on getting the zoom feature back?

Comment: Why the `microsoft` tag?

Comment: Open System Preferences>Accessibility>Zoom. Is 'Use scroll gesture with modifier keys to zoom' configured with Control and enabled?

Answer (score 1):

Apple changed this default behavior in 10.8 Mountain Lion.

To re-enable the behavior you're accustomed to:

1. Open System Preferences
2. Click on Accessibility
3. Click on Zoom
4. Check the box next to "Use scroll gesture with modifier keys to zoom"
5. *optional* - You can change the modifier key (*control* by default) that is used in the dropdown box below

From a support perspective I can understand why Apple disabled this.  I've personally helped probably upwards of 20 people who have inadvertently zoomed in and have not known what they did or how to undo it.  I can only imagine that AppleCare phone support gets many calls about this, which I'm sure is difficult to figure out based on the descriptions people give.

Changing the default behavior would kill off the majority of those calls for new 10.8 users who have no idea what the feature is for while leaving the option there for those of us that use it from time to time.

Hope that helps!

Comment: In System Preferences/Accessibility, you can also click the checkbox "Show Accessibility status in menubar" to keep an eye on what's turned on and what's off.